# How to use csv with python as an expert?

Tags: python, loops, csv, read.csv

I'm just getting started on python programming.

Here is an example of my `CSV` file :

| Name | tag. | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cool | cool,fun | cool ... |
| Cell | Cell,phone | Cell ... |
| Rang | first,third | rang ... |

The print with the `CSV` module gives me a list of all rows, either:

```
['cool',''cool,fun'','cool...']
['cell',''cell,phone'','cell...']
```

What I want to do is to printer that cool or cell, phone

Comment: Can you add to your question a _clear expected output_ ? Also, are you open to external libraries ?

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming! What you are looking for is a way to format the output. The csv module itself works very well out of the box. Take a look at Alan's answer, please. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

---

I'm also new to programming, but I think I know what you're asking.

---

## How to use CSV module in python

### The answer for your question

- What you asked "printer that cool or cell, phone" is easy to implement, you can try below code in terminal:

---

```
import csv
with open('your_file_path', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = list(reader)
    print(rows[1][0])
    print(rows[2][1])
```

---

### My thoughts

- Actually, you should consider the following two points when understanding this problem:

1. Content, that is, the **content** you want to print in your terminal, you need to first make sure that what you want is a specific row or column or a specific cell;
2. The format, that is, the **list** you side or those **quotation marks**, these are the types of data in the file, and they must be carefully distinguished.

---

In addition, it would be better for you to read some articles or materials processed about CSV module, such as the following:

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#reader-objects

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-rows-from-a-csv-file-in-python

> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/working-with-csv-files-in-python-programming

---

I am also unskilled in many places, please forgive me if there are mistakes or omissions.